# keeping connection alive to websocket when using ServerWebSocketContainer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I was trying to create a websocket based application where the server needs to keep the connection alive with the clients using heartbeat.
I checked  the server  `ServerWebSocketContainer.SockJsServiceOptions` class for the same, but could not use it. I am using the code from the spring-integration sample

```
@Bean
ServerWebSocketContainer serverWebSocketContainer() {
    return new ServerWebSocketContainer("/messages").withSockJs();
}

@Bean
MessageHandler webSocketOutboundAdapter() {
    return new WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler(serverWebSocketContainer());
}

@Bean(name = "webSocketFlow.input")
MessageChannel requestChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow webSocketFlow() {
    return f -> {
        Function<Message , Object> splitter = m -> serverWebSocketContainer()
                .getSessions()
                .keySet()
                .stream()
                .map(s -> MessageBuilder.fromMessage(m)
                        .setHeader(SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER, s)
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        f.split( Message.class, splitter)
                .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
                .handle(webSocketOutboundAdapter());
    };
}

@RequestMapping("/hi/{name}")
public void send(@PathVariable String name) {
    requestChannel().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(name).build());
}
```

Please let me know how can I set the heartbeat options ensure the connection is kept alive unless the client de-registers itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you got it right, but missed a bit of convenience :-).
You can configure it like this:

```
@Bean
ServerWebSocketContainer serverWebSocketContainer() {
    return new ServerWebSocketContainer("/messages")
          .withSockJs(new ServerWebSocketContainer.SockJsServiceOptions()
                                  .setHeartbeatTime(60_000));
}
```

Although it isn't clear for me why you need to configure it at all because of this:

```
/**
 * The amount of time in milliseconds when the server has not sent any
 * messages and after which the server should send a heartbeat frame to the
 * client in order to keep the connection from breaking.
 * <p>The default value is 25,000 (25 seconds).
 */
public SockJsServiceRegistration setHeartbeatTime(long heartbeatTime) {
    this.heartbeatTime = heartbeatTime;
    return this;
}
```

**UPDATE**

In the Spring Integration Samples we have something like [stomp-chat](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/stomp-chat) application.

I have done there something like this to the `stomp-server.xml`:

```
<int-websocket:server-container id="serverWebSocketContainer" path="/chat">
    <int-websocket:sockjs heartbeat-time="10000"/>
</int-websocket:server-container>
```

Added this to the `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session=trace
```

And this to the `index.html`:

```
sock.onheartbeat = function() {
    console.log('heartbeat');
};
```

After connecting the client I see this in the server log:

```
2015-10-13 19:03:06.574 TRACE 7960 --- [       SockJS-3] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Writing SockJsFrame content='h'
2015-10-13 19:03:06.574 TRACE 7960 --- [       SockJS-3] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Cancelling heartbeat in session sogfe2dn
2015-10-13 19:03:06.574 TRACE 7960 --- [       SockJS-3] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Scheduled heartbeat in session sogfe2dn
2015-10-13 19:03:16.576 TRACE 7960 --- [       SockJS-8] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Preparing to write SockJsFrame content='h'
2015-10-13 19:03:16.576 TRACE 7960 --- [       SockJS-8] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Writing SockJsFrame content='h'
2015-10-13 19:03:16.576 TRACE 7960 --- [       SockJS-8] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Cancelling heartbeat in session sogfe2dn
2015-10-13 19:03:16.576 TRACE 7960 --- [       SockJS-8] s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession : Scheduled heartbeat in session sogfe2dn
```

In the browser's console I see this after:

[image]

So, looks like `heart-beat` feature works well...

Comment: After 5-6 minutes, the connection is getting stale and timed-out. So, I need a way to keep the connection alive.

Comment: Well. Maybe that is the TTL of your HTTP session ?.. Dead HTTP session causes closing for all its WebSocket sessions. Let me know your position on the matter.

Comment: I am using `WebSocketConnectionManager()` to establish connection using the WS protocol from the client. There is no HTTP involved here. Pardon me if i am missing something

Comment: Please, take a look to an update for my answer. According to your last comments: well, you missed a bit how WebSocket protocol works. It really starts from the HTTP and some particular request with the `Upgrade:"websocket"` header.

Comment: Thanks. It worked after correcting the client side code

Comment: Great! Would you mind sharing that fix? As an edit to your question and comment here to notify me would be enough.

Comment: The server was sending the heartbeat but it was not being handled on the client side. Due to this when heartbeats were getting missed the connection was getting closed.

Comment: Please, share what you have fixed on the client side. Maybe we had missed anything in our code...